# Sonartype Nexus (in Docker) behind Nginx "fails to determin hostename"

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nexus, nginx-reverse-proxy

I managed to setup a Nexus on my Server. With a tiny problem. This log occurs during startup:

`2023-08-06 18:57:34,454+0000 ERROR [Thread-75] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.node.orient.OrientLocalNodeAccess - Failed to determine hostname, using nodeId instead.`

I'd like to make this hostname detection work and so far I found nothing about that error message related to Nexus.

## Impact

For now I found out that the HTML view doesn't work. There is a redirect from

`https://nexus.mydomain.de/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-central`

to

`https://[2003:c3:5f42:ef1d:e5e7:36f8:e7a9:69a8]/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-central/`

which obviosly cannot be found.

I have not yet tested, if I can push something to the repository.

## Architecture

The traffic runs through a nginx reverse proxy with this config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name nexus.mydomain.de;
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:30030;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
}
```

The traffic is then forwarded to port 30030 where the Nexus Docker container is listening. I'm running it with docker-compose not Docker Swarm. Here is the short compose file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3:3.58.1
    volumes:
      - "/some/path/nexus:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "30030:8081"
```

## Update 1 week later

I just learned about the [Base URL Capability](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/capabilities/base-url-capability) in the settings which is exactly for the case of running Nexus behind a reverse proxy. But the documentation says it is only used for e-mail notifications.

Without (remembering) having changed somenthing else now the redirection looks different than last week:

`https://87.180.101.212/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-central/`

Apperantly its now using the IPv4 address of my nexus container instead of IPv6.